# Where is the Customer View tab added?

Tags: tabs

On the following page:

Customers -> Manage Customers -> Click on a customer

It shows a list of tabs on the left side, one of which is called "Customer View".

But when I look at Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs::_beforeToHtml, I see that the function call to addTab() is commented out for the "Customer View" tab.

So where is the Customer View tab being added from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This block comes from layout xml. Goto "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customer.xml" and look "adminhtml_customer_edit" handler. Code sample look like;

```
<block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tabs" name="customer_edit_tabs">
            <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view" name="customer_edit_tab_view" template="customer/tab/view.phtml">
                <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_sales" name="sales" template="customer/tab/view/sales.phtml" before="-" />
                <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_accordion" name="accordion" />
            </block>
            <action method="addTab"><name>customer_edit_tab_view</name><block>customer_edit_tab_view</block></action>
        </block>
```

Goto "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml" This template is responsible for content.

Comment: Thanks, I opened that template file and found the block associated with it, opened that and found a getTabLabel function. This still doesn't really tell me how the first tab in the tab list gets created, as I was looking to remove the first, but I think I will now just remove the second tab and rename the first.